# Bizzare android table row issue

Tags: android, android-view, android-tablelayout, tablerow

I am programmatically trying to add views to my table layout in Android. But I am not able to add more than 1 view to my row. It only renders the first view. The second column is empty. My code is as below.

```
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow tr2 = new TableRow(this);
    TextView productNumber = new TextView(this);
    productNumber.setText("PRODUCT NUMBER: " + b[0].getProduct_id());
    productNumber.setTextSize(18);
    productNumber.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    productNumber.setPadding(20, 5, 20, 5);
    tr1.addView(productNumber);
    TextView productDesc = new TextView(this);
    productDesc.setText("PRODUCT DESCRIPTION: " + b[0].getItem_description());
    productDesc.setTextSize(18);
    productDesc.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    productDesc.setPadding(20, 5, 20, 5);
    tr2.addView(productDesc);
    productNumber.setLayoutParams(lp);
    productDesc.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tl.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    tl.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tl.addView(tr2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



    for (ProductBean p: b) {
        TableRow lineSeparator = new TableRow(this.getApplicationContext());
        View line = new View(this.getApplicationContext());
        line.setMinimumHeight(1);
        line.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        line.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
        lineSeparator.addView(line);
        tl.addView(lineSeparator);
        Set<String> headers = p.getAttr().keySet();

    //Till here it works fine. The following code seems to not add more than 1 view

        for (String s: headers) {
            Log.i("S", "S: " + p.getAttr().get(s));
            TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView.setText(s);
            textView.setPadding(20, 5, 20, 5);
            textView.setTextSize(15);
            tableRow.addView(textView);
            textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            textView.setText(p.getAttr().get(s));
            textView.setPadding(20, 5, 20, 5);
            textView.setTextSize(15);
            tableRow.addView(textView); //This view is not rendered.
            tl.addView(tableRow);
        }
    }
```

However, I tried the following in a separate activity and layout and it worked successfully. Hello is one column and World another.

```
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        TextView textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText("Hello");
        tableRow.addView(textView);
        textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText("World"); 
        tableRow.addView(textView);
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
```

Why is my code not rendering the second view then? I am able to log the contents of both the textviews but it just doesn't render the second view in the row. Please help. I am utterly lost, been beating my head over it for 12 hours now!!

Comment: Why are you adding  `tableRow.addView(textView);` two times in your for loop?

Comment: That's how a second column is added. You can try running the second code snippet. Works just fine. Basically, once the textView is complete, add it and then redefine it to add another column.

Comment: @AS and also you set the same padding  `textView.setPadding(20, 5, 20, 5);` change the padding to second `TextView` and try.

Comment: What is the type of the object returned from p.getAttr().get(s)?  Have you tried adding toString()?  p.getAttr().get(s).toString()  It seems like the text may be getting set to empty and so you are not seeing it in the table row.

Comment: Like I expected, changing padding didn't work. Why would it? If you look at the second snippet, there is no padding. So both views in that have same padding which is none. If that works, why should padding make any difference. The point is for some reason the second instance of the textView is not being rendered in my code.

Comment: @DougSimonton I am able to log it using Log.i, however I can try what you suggest but I don't think that is the issue. Cause I tried just adding the second instance of textView and leave out the first and that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem and the solution as well. Actually my xml had just one scroll view and one table layout within that. The first two textviews that I add and then the table rows that I add, would span the width of the entire screen and thus the first column of the table would occupy the whole width of the screen.

```
   tl.addView(tr1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   tl.addView(tr2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Now I have created a separate LinearLayout outside the scroll view and adding the content of these two rows above to the LinearLayout. Works fine!